# Unity C# Button onClick Method How To Get GameObject Automatically

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to get Gameobject automatically with script?

I need know. button OnClick method empty if the scene changes. My gameObject tpye Don'tDestroyLoad.

[image: unity button onClick method]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the object in the field you can use a script to then have `GameObject gameObjectToClick` to be changed. Use the inspector to add a script to the button called "Click", then drag the button object into the object field shown in the screenshot and then select the function OnClick(). Click has the following code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Click : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject gameObjectToClick;
    void OnClick(){
         gameObjectToClick.SpecialFunction(); //call special function you wanted to call
    }
}
```

Simply change `gameObjectToClick` through another script how you would normally achieve it and change it (e.g `button.GetComponent<Click>().gameObjectToClick = otherGameObject`) Also change `SpecialFunction()` to the function you would have set in the dropdown menu in the screenshot.